# Finding Specific Users - by their interested tags

Tags: feature-request

I am new in iPhone development.

Here - I need to find out the people who are enrolled with iPhone tag?

It means,

I want to find out peoples who have added iPhone, cococa, objective c as their interested tag.

So, I can read their questions & answers,
& by doing this I can come to know beginners problem & how to face it.

Anyone know - how to filter user's by their category?

Thanks for Helping me.

Comment: This could help you find out what those that tag iphone are also interested in. Who knows, maybe they like Macs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this isn't a social networking site, so we don't connect you with other users.

Second, you actually don't need to find users based on their tags, you can look at all questions within a specific tag. I would think this would be much more helpful to you in the long run. As an aside, you will, with enough time, recognize the active users in the iphone community and at that point you may want to view what other questions they ask/answer.

Edit:

Ok your comment clarifies the question a bit. If you look at the specific tag and click on the stats portion you will see stats on it ([blog post about the stats feature](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/new-tag-statistics/))

For example for [Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=iphone&sort=stats&pagesize=50)

Comment: @Nathan Koop - Mr. You misunderstand me. I know this is not a social networking site. I want to know who has the highest reputation by tags. So, I can read answers. I am not interested here to make any social networks. I need is - "Knowledge".

Comment: @Nathan Koop - That's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to one of those tags and then to the stats tab, this should show user's the are relatively active answering and asking questions on those tags. However, if you're simply looking to learn new things and pick up what you can, I would really just recommend looking through the questions in the tags you're trying to learn. In doing this you will likely quickly pick up on who some of the "experts" are, and regardless, through the voting system, you should be able to learn things from many of the questions. And it doesn't matter if the person with the highest voted and/or accepted answer on a particular question has a high overall rep, they still can be "trusted" in their answer to that specific questions; at least they roughly have the communities collective approval.

Note, looking through the stats tab of a tag will not tell you if the person has the tag favorited or not, but I believe it gets you to your end goal. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=iphone&sort=stats&pagesize=50) should get you to list for the `iphone` tag.